# Querying Cassandra in C#

Tags: c#, cassandra, cql

I have the following table in a timeseries keyspace:

```
CREATE TABLE underlying_data (
  symbol text,
  ask decimal,
  bid decimal,
  ts bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((symbol))
) WITH
  bloom_filter_fp_chance=0.010000 AND
  caching='KEYS_ONLY' AND
  comment='' AND
  dclocal_read_repair_chance=0.100000 AND
  gc_grace_seconds=864000 AND
  index_interval=128 AND
  read_repair_chance=0.000000 AND
  replicate_on_write='true' AND
  populate_io_cache_on_flush='false' AND
  default_time_to_live=0 AND
  speculative_retry='99.0PERCENTILE' AND
  memtable_flush_period_in_ms=0 AND
  compaction={'class': 'SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'} AND
  compression={'sstable_compression': 'LZ4Compressor'};

CREATE INDEX underlying_data_ts_idx ON underlying_data (ts);

cqlsh:timeseries>
```

I try to query this table from C# after inserting some items like this:

```
static long ninetySeventyTicks = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1).Ticks;

Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder().AddContactPoint("127.0.0.1").Build();
ISession session = cluster.Connect("timeseries");

RowSet result  = session.Execute("SELECT symbol, ts FROM underlying_data WHERE ts > " 
                + ninetySeventyTicks.ToString() 
                + " and symbol = 'SPX'"
                //+ "AllowFiltering"
                + ";");

            rows = result.GetRows();
```

But I get an exception:

```
Message = "No indexed columns present in by-columns clause with Equal operator"
```

I copied this example from a book on querying cassandra. The only difference is that the book uses CQL not the C# driver.

Should this work and if so, what is the suggested solution?

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the best policy when it comes to secondary indexes, is to avoid using them.

You can easily get this query to work by adding `ts` to the PRIMARY KEY.

```
PRIMARY KEY (symbol,ts)
```

Here, `symbol` is the partitioning key, and `ts` is the clustering key.  That will allow you to specify a `symbol` and filter your results based on the value of `ts`.